# Show that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (x+n\pi)^{-2} = \sin^{-2}(x) $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you show that 
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (x+n\pi)^{-2} = \sin^{-2}(x)
$$
It is noted that if you make the substitution $x=x+2\pi$ the relation remains unchanged, but how can you show that relation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compact form of the series $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} {1\over (x-n)^2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65726/compact-form-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-infty-infty-1-over-x-n2)

Comment: i think expression is wrong as for $x=0$ r.h.s tends to infinity but l.h.s is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: oh i forgot $n=0$ also comes

Answer (score 6):

If we start from the Weierstrass product for the sine function:
$$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z} = \prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)\tag{1}$$
we just have to consider $\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\log(\cdot)$ of both sides.