# Various evaluations of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, special-functions, polygamma

I recently ran into this series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}$$

Of course this is just a special case of the Beta Dirichlet Function , for $s=3$.

I had given the following solution:
$$\begin{aligned} 
1-\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{5^3}-\cdots &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\left ( 2n+1 \right )^3} \\  
 &\overset{(*)}{=} \left ( 1+\frac{1}{5^3}+\frac{1}{9^3}+\cdots \right )-\left ( \frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{7^3}+\frac{1}{11^3}+\cdots \right )\\  
 &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left ( 4n+1 \right )^3} \; -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left ( 4n+3 \right )^3} \\  
 &= -\frac{1}{2\cdot 4^3}\psi^{(2)}\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )+\frac{1}{2\cdot 4^3}\psi^{(2)}\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )=\frac{1}{2\cdot 4^3}\left [ \psi^{(2)}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{4} \right )-\psi^{(2)}\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right ) \right ]\\ 
 &=\frac{1}{2\cdot 4^3}\left [ 2\pi^3 \cot \frac{\pi}{4} \csc^2 \frac{\pi}{4}  \right ] \\ 
 &=\frac{\pi^3 \cot \frac{\pi}{4}\csc^2 \frac{\pi}{4}}{4^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32} 
\end{aligned}$$

where I used polygamma identities and made use of the absolute convergence of the series at $(*)$ in order to re-arrange the terms.

*Any other approach using Fourier Series, or contour integration around a square, if that is possible?*

Comment: This [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510363/a-series-related-to-zeta-3) may be of interest too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Method by Fourier Series**

Consider the function $f(x) = x(1 - x)$, $0 \le x \le 1$. It has Fourier sine series expansion

$$f(x) = \frac{8}{\pi^3}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}\sin{(2n-1)\pi x}.$$

Setting $x = \frac{1}{2}$ results in

$$\frac{1}{4} = \frac{8}{\pi^3}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3},$$

or

$$\frac{\pi^3}{32} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}.$$

By reindexing the sum we can write

$$\frac{\pi^3}{32} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}.$$

**Method by Contour Integration**

Let $g(z) = \frac{1}{(2z - 1)^3}$. Then $g$ has only one pole of order $3$ at $z = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $N$ be a positive integer, and consider the contour integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_N} \pi\csc \pi z\, g(z)\, dz,$$

where $\Gamma_N$ is a positively oriented square with vertices at $\left(N + \frac{1}{2}\right)(\pm 1 \pm i)$. The residue theorem gives

\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_N} \pi \csc \pi z\, g(z)\, dz &= \sum_{n = -N}^N \operatorname{Res}\limits_{z = n} \pi \csc \pi z\, g(z) + \operatorname{Res}\limits_{z = \frac{1}{2}} \pi \csc \pi z\, g(z)\\
&= \sum_{n = -N}^N (-1)^n g(n) + \frac{\pi^3}{16}.
\end{align}

For $|z| \ge 1$, $|g(z)| \le |z|^{-3}$. Thus, $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_N} \pi \csc \pi z\, g(z)\, dz \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad N \to \infty.$$

Hence

$$0 = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty (-1)^n g(n) + \frac{\pi^3}{16}$$

that is,

$$\frac{\pi^3}{16} = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}.$$

Now

\begin{align}\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3} &= \sum_{n = -\infty}^0 \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}\\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^3} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}\\
& = 2\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}.
\end{align}

Thus

$$\frac{\pi^3}{16} = 2\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}.$$

Finally, we have

$$\frac{\pi^3}{32} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}.$$

Comment: (+1) for this nice Fourier series.. Could you tell me how you came up with this function?? $f(x)=x(1-x), x \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: By considering the Fourier sines of $x$ and $x^2$.

Comment: I really like the contour integration part...

Answer (score 6):

Differentiating twice the logarithm of the Weierstrass representation of sine gives
$$ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} {1\over (z+n)^2}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{\sin^{2}(\pi z)} $$
[(as i've been answered in here.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169346/show-that-sum-n-infty-infty-xn-pi-2-sin-2x)

Now differentiate once more and consider $z=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: do you have an alternative proof using Fourier series for the identity you used?

Comment: Well done and a (+1) for making use of the partial fraction expansion of $\csc^2(\pi z)$.  
Note that that expansion can be developed from the Fourier Series of $\cos(xy)$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$.  See my answer [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091415/how-to-prove-that-csc2x-sum-infty-infty-frac1x-n-pi2/3091468#3091468) and relatedly see the Appendix in my answer [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913576#1913576).

Comment: The can also be derived from [this technique by 3blue1brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls).

Answer (score 4):

I do not know how much this could help you; so forgive me if I am out off topic.

Rewriting a little the expression $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}x^n=\frac{1}{8} \,\Phi \left(-x,3,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ where appears the Lerch transcendent function. Now, using $x=1$, we can get the result.

Comment: Ι don't know Lerch function... so ...

Answer (score 4):

We begin with an integral representation:$$S:=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}dx.$$The integrand is even, so$$S=\frac14\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}dx.$$Or with $e^{-x}=\tan t$,$$S=\frac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln^2(\tan t)dt.$$Since $\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{2k-1}tdt=\frac{\pi}{2}\csc(k\pi)$,$$S=\frac{\pi}{32}\left.\left(\partial_k^2\csc(k\pi)\right)\right|_{k=\frac12}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}\left(\csc\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\left(\cot^2\frac{\pi}{2}+\csc^2\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi^3}{32}.$$

Answer (score 4):

This is $\beta(3)$, where $\beta(x)$ is the [Dirichlet Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function). The derivation below is taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613341).

---

**The Dirichlet Beta Function**
$$
\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}\tag1
$$
is known as the [Dirichlet beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function). As shown below,
$$
\beta(3)=\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}\tag2
$$

---

**Recurrence for $\boldsymbol{\beta(2n+1)}$**

We can develop a recurrence for $\beta(2k+1)$. First, the generating function for $\beta(2k+1)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta(2k+1) x^{2k+1}\\
     &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)^{2k+1}\\
     &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\frac{x}{2n+1}}{1-\left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)^2}\\
     &= \frac{x}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{1}{2n+1+x}+\frac{1}{2n+1-x}\right)\\
     &= \frac{x}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1+x}\\
     &= \frac{x}{4} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{n+\tfrac{1+x}{2}}\\
     &= \frac{x}{4} \pi \csc\left(\pi\tfrac{1+x}{2}\right)\\[3pt]
     &= \frac{\pi}{4} x \sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
where we use $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) to get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+z}
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac2{2n+z}-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac1{n+z}\\[3pt]
&=\pi\cot(\pi z/2)-\pi\cot(\pi z)\\[9pt]
&=\pi\csc(\pi z)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
We can use equation $(3)$ to develop a recurrence relation:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4} x
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} x\right) f(x)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{(\frac{\pi}{2} x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\;\beta(2n-2k+1)x^{2n-2k+1}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-\pi^2/4)^k}{(2k)!}\;\beta(2n-2k+1)x^{2n+1}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
For $n=0$, we can use the arctan series to get
$$
\beta(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}\tag{6}
$$
and for $n\gt0$, $(5)$ gives
$$
\beta(2n+1) = -\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-\pi^2/4)^k}{(2k)!}\;\beta(2n-2k+1)\tag{7}
$$
Recursion $(7)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\beta(1)&=\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\beta(3)&=\frac{\pi^3}{32}\\
\beta(5)&=\frac{5\pi^5}{1536}\\
\beta(7)&=\frac{61\pi^7}{184320}\\
\beta(9)&=\frac{277\pi^9}{8257536}\\
\beta(11)&=\frac{50521\pi^{11}}{14863564800}\\
\beta(13)&=\frac{540553\pi^{13}}{1569592442880}\\
\beta(15)&=\frac{199360981\pi^{15}}{5713316492083200}\\
\beta(17)&=\frac{3878302429\pi^{17}}{1096956766479974400}\\
\beta(19)&=\frac{2404879675441\pi^{19}}{6713375410857443328000}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, and it combines integration and probability.

First off, consider the triple integral:

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2y^2z^2}dzdydx.$$

Convert this integrand into a geometric series:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(xyz)^{2n}.$$
Replace the integrand with this series and integrate term by term to get that: $$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}.$$

Now we proceed to evaluate $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2y^2z^2}dzdydx.$$ Make the change of variables $$x=\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos(v)},y=\frac{\sin(v)}{\cos(w)},z=\frac{\sin(w)}{\cos(u)}$$ which has a nice Jacobian $\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}=1+x^2y^2z^2$ that cancels with the integrand. The region of integration is the open polytope $U$ described by inequalities $$0<u+v<\frac{\pi}{2},0<v+w<\frac{\pi}{2},0<u+w<\frac{\pi}{2}, u,v,w>0.$$ We need to compute the volume of $U$ to get the value of $I$.

For the purpose of this proof, we consider the scaled polytope $V$ defined by inequalities:  $$0<u+v<1,0<v+w<1,0<u+w<1, u,v,w>0.$$ Notice $$\text{Vol}(U)=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3 \text{Vol}(V)$$ where $\text{Vol}$ means volume. 
We compute $\text{Vol}(V)$ through probability.

Suppose $n=(n_1,n_2,n_3) \in V.$ We first intend to find the probability: $$\text{Pr}\left(n\in V \cap \text{each } n_i <\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ It turns out that:
$$\text{Pr}\left(n\in V \cap \text{each } n_i <\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3=\frac{1}{8}.$$ This is the case because $n$ would lie in the open hypercube $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)^3,$ and one can verify that $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \subset V.$
Next, we intend to find the probability: $$\text{Pr}\left(n\in V \cap \text{exactly one } n_i \geq \frac{1}{2}\right)$$ It turns out that:
$$\text{Pr}\left(n\in V \cap \text{exactly one } n_i \geq \frac{1}{2}\right)=3\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{1-x}=\frac{1}{8}.$$
Here, to get this answer, I computed the probability $\text{Pr}\left(n\in V \cap  n_1 \geq \frac{1}{2}\right)$ and multiplied this answer by $3$ to account for all the possible $3$ cases of this event happening.

Notice that we cannot have more than one $n_i \geq \frac{1}{2}$ at the same time, as this will violate the constraints of $V$. This means we add up the computed probabilities to get that : $$\text{Vol}(V)=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{4}.$$ This means that 
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\text{Vol}(U)=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3 \text{Vol}(V)=\left(\frac{\pi^3}{8}\right)\frac{1}{4}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}.$$