# $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bigg[ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\Bigg] $

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

find the sum of the series, no solution was provided.

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bigg[  \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\Bigg] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

I've tried a few many ways, I'll add my attempts in but they weren't correct

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty+(%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5En%7D%7B(2n%2B1)%5E3%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B(2n%2B1)%5E2%7D)

Comment: @DMHO yes that works, but it doesn't provide step by step example solution?

Comment: According to WolframAlpha (link given above), the answer is $\dfrac1{64} (\zeta(3, 1/4) - \zeta(3, 3/4) + 8 \pi^2)≈2.20265$, which is not a nice solution.

Comment: I didn't even finish my comment @hit

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)$ is straightforward; for the remaining part have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas

Answer (score 6):

[In this mathstackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195285/various-evaluations-of-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n13), an answer shows how a Fourier expansion of $x(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$ gives $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}.$$ On the other hand, we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$ So, the two results put together gives $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bigg[  \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\Bigg] =\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}+\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}.$$