# Prove $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions

> I would like to see the ways that *you* prove that $$\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}.$$All methods are welcome.

**My Proof:**

We start by breaking up the sum as 
$$S=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{(4n+1)^3}-\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{(4n+3)^3}$$
and seeing that this can be expressed in terms of the polygamma function:
$$S=\frac1{2^7}\left[\psi_2\left(\frac34\right)-\psi_2\left(\frac14\right)\right].$$
Then using
$$\psi_s(z)=\int_0^1\frac{t^{z-1}}{t-1}\ln^s(t)dt$$
we have 
$$S=\frac{1}{2^7}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(x)}{x-1}(x^{-1/4}-x^{-3/4})dx.$$
Then taking advantage of $x\mapsto 1/x$, 
$$S=\frac1{2^7}\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^2(x)}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x^{1/2}}{x^{3/4}}dx.$$
Then $x\mapsto x^4$ cleans this up quite nicely:
$$S=\frac12\int_1^\infty \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^4}\ln^2(x)dx=\frac12\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^2(x)}{x^2+1}dx.$$
Then we use a little symmetry:
$$S=\frac14\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(x)}{x^2+1}dx.$$
Finally, we use $x\mapsto\tan x$:
$$S=\frac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln^2(\tan x)dx.$$
We immediately recognize this as 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln^2(\tan x)dx=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^2\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1+a}2)\Gamma(\frac{1-a}{2})}2\bigg|_{a=0}$$
but the Gamma reflection formula gives this as 
$$\frac\pi2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^2\frac{1}{\cos\frac{\pi a}{2}}\bigg|_{a=0}=\frac{\pi^3}{8},$$
which provides our result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195285/various-evaluations-of-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n13

Comment: I've just posted an answer on the older question that starts in a similar way to your approach, but doesn't need knowledge of $\psi$ because of a cunning symmetry argument.

Comment: I've also moved my answer there.